# user_splits option in h2o.partialplot

Tags: h2o

I'm trying to specify user split points for a partial dependence plot with H2o, but I can't figure out how to code for this.

The documentation says:

> A two-level nested list containing user defined split points for pdp plots for each column. If there are two columns using user defined split points, there should be two lists in the nested list. Inside each list, the first element is the column name followed by values defined by the user.

I've tried looking for user tests on github, but couldn't find anything.

```
h2o.partialPlot(data
     , cols = "change"
     , user_splits = list(list("change"), list(0,.01,.02))
     , object = h2o.getModel("gbm_model")
     , plot = FALSE)
```

I get the following error:

Error in `[.H2OFrame`(data, csname) : Row must be selected as an integer index, character, logical, or H2OFrame but got list

If i remove the user_splits line of code, I get no error.

Answer (score 1):

```
changesplit <- c(0,.01,.02)
usersplit <- list(c("change", changesplit))
h2o.partialPlot(data
     , cols = "change"
     , user_splits = usersplit 
     , object = h2o.getModel("gbm_model")
     , plot = FALSE)
```

I don't know why this works.  The documentation isn't particularly helpful. 
Because

```
changesplit <- c(0,.01,.02)
is.list(changesplit)
[1] FALSE

is.list(c("change", changesplit))
[1] FALSE
```

If you want to have additional variables and splits

```
usersplit <- list(
   c("change", changesplit)
   , c("x", seq(1:10,by = 1))
)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.